# Does Removing An Item From QTableWidget Deletes Object(s) Contained by The Item?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Qt 5.15.2 is used with C++ in the project that I am working on. Unfortunately, I could not find the event that triggers the deletion of an object?

What could trigger the lambda function given below?

```
auto deletionConnection = connect(myCustomQObject, &QWidget::deleted, [myCustomQObject, this, serverName] (){
            communicationDeleted(serverName);
    });
```

It is clear that when myCustomQObject object is deleted, the program execution enters inside of this lambda function. *communicationDeleted(serverName)* is another signal.
But I couldnt find the event that deletes this myCustomQObject object. The code block that contains this connection is given below.

```
void myCustomTableWidget::addRow(const QString& serverName)
{
    myCustomQObject* newCustomQObject = new myCustomQObject(this);
    QWidget* newCellWidget = new QWidget();


    QHBoxLayout* rowLayout = new QHBoxLayout(newCellWidget);
    rowLayout->addWidget(myCustomQObject);

    newCellWidget->setLayout(rowLayout);

    m_ui->tableServers->insertRow(m_rowCount);
    m_ui->tableServers->setCellWidget(newCellWidget);

    auto deletionConnection = connect(myCustomQObject, &QWidget::deleted, [myCustomQObject, this, serverName] (){
            communicationDeleted(serverName);
    });

    m_->deletionConnections.pushBack(deletionConnection);
    ...
}
```

I suspected another slot *myCustomTableWidget::deleteRow(qint32)* cause deletion of the object. But if I have multiple items on the table and remove lets say three of them, the execution enters the breakpoint set in *deleteRow(qint32)* three times. Yet, I have seen that later in the process, the lambda is executed. Am I right that, removing a row from a table cause the item object to be deleted? Or should I focus on different place?

```
void myCustomTableWidget::deleteRow(qint32 rowIndex)
{
    m_ui->tableServers->removeRow(rowIndex);
    m_rowCount--;
}
```

Comment: Run your program under a debugger. The stack trace should reveal the signal or slot that triggered `deleted` plain as day.

Comment: @Botje thank you for your suggestion. But I have a problem. We are using Visual Studio. The debugger is quite well and tried to trace the program execution from the "Call Stack". However, all of the functions from that lambda to main, belongs to Qt functions and there are lots of them! So after one of the place, the code must enter the code block of ours. But I dont know how to find the correct place.

Comment: Why don't you do something (print, whatever) in the destructor of your contained object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt's `QTableWidget`, `setCellWidget()` internally [calls `setIndexWidget()` of `QAbstractItemView`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v5.15.2/src/widgets/itemviews/qtablewidget.cpp#L2358). That in turn [registers the widget as a 'static editor'](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v5.15.2/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#L3241).

When any model items are removed in a Qt item view, the `rowsAboutToBeRemoved()` slot of `QAbstractItemView` is called. That in turn [calls `d->releaseEditor()` on the widget](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v5.15.2/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#L3429). For static editors the `releaseEditor()` function [calls `editor->deleteLater()`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v5.15.2/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview_p.h#L222) to actually delete the widget.

All subclasses of `QObject` have a [`deleteLater()` slot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater). The reason this exists is the following: suppose your widget is a push button, and you connect that push button's `clicked()` signal with a slot that removes the row the widget it. If an item view were to then just call `delete widget;` the widget would be deleted while its own event handler for the `clicked()` signal is still active. This will likely cause memory corruption, because you shouldn't delete objects that are still being used. Qt avoids these types problems by using `deleteLater()` in many places: objects are marked to be deleted, but only when control is given back to the event loop (i.e. the current event handler has exited), all objects marked for deletion in this manner are also removed, which is now safe to do, because the objects are no longer being used.

(Btw. this is the reason why `dialog.exec()` and/or `QApplication::processEvents()` can be the cause of weird bugs in some cases.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @chris_se. This explains a lot. I said, "So after one of the place, the code must enter the code block of ours." to the comment of Botje. I thought that the code will return somehow to our code blocks. But I understand that all of our code has already been executed and Qt handles necessary jobs before ending the execution. On of them is deleting objects that are marked to be deleted. I will try to debug our code again with keeping this information on my mind. After that, I can accept your answer.

Comment: Basically the call stack when you remove the row is going to be something along the lines of: `app.run()` in `main()` -> Qt event loop internals -> Qt event handler (QEvent* and friends) -> `emit signal()` -> your slot -> remove the row from table -> QTableWidget internals -> `deleteLater()`; the call stack of the actual deletion is going to be `app.run()` in `main()` -> Qt event loop internals -> actually delete object -> destructor -> `emit destroyed()` -> your handler for the `destroyed` signal.